# How to correctly access atributes in classes from other class

Tags: kotlin, oop

Changing a var can lead to problems inside a class/program.

I asked me, how to store a variable correctly inside a class, so that it is prevented from unauthorized access from outside, or an other class.

Also it should prevent encapsulation.

- With the getter, something from outside knows about attributs inside the class.
- With the backingField its more hidden inside the class.

What would be the right approach?

```
class sleepingRoom {
 var beds = 2
     get() = field
     set(value) {
         // do something
     }

 private var _beds2 = 2
 val beds2: Int
     get() = _beds2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the concept of properties in Kotlin, it should not be necessary to worry about that. Taking your example of the number of beds in a bedroom, if you don't have any further constraints, you can simply define a property:

```
class SleepingRoom {
  var beds = 2
}
```

This is equivalent to Java code where you have a private field together with a getter and a setter, but with a lot less boilerplate code. If you don't want to have a setter, then just change `var` to `val`.

If later you decide that you want to change the inner semantics of your property `beds`, nothing stops you from that. You can define an explicit getter or setter, another backing property, a property delegator. This may drastically change the behavior of your property, but for usages of the property, nothing of that is visible. It still remains just a property `beds`.